# Find the asymptotic relative efficiency for two estimators from a Poisson family

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence

If two estimators $W_n$ and $V_n$ satisfy $$\sqrt n[W_n - \tau(\theta)] \rightarrow n[0,\sigma^2_W] \\ \sqrt n [V_n - \tau(\theta)] \rightarrow n[0, \sigma^2_V] $$ in distribution then the asymptotic relative efficiency (ARE) of $V_n$ with respect to $W_n$ is $$ ARE(V_n, W_n) = \frac{\sigma^2_W}{\sigma^2_V} .$$

> Consider a random sample of size $n$ from a Poisson population with mean $\lambda$. I am asked to find the $ARE(\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n \bar x}, e^{-\bar x})$ where $\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n \bar x}$ is the uniformly minimum variance unbiased estimator of $e^{-\lambda}$ and $e^{-\bar x}$ is the maximum likelihood estimator of $e^{- \lambda}$

Its easy to see from the delta method that $$ \sqrt n[e^{-\bar x} -e^{- \lambda} ] \rightarrow n[0,\lambda e^{-2 \lambda}] $$ which takes care of finding the asymptotic variance of the MLE, $\sigma^2_{MLE} = \lambda e^{-2\lambda}$. 
But I run into a problem when trying to do the same for the UMVUE. First we note that $$ \sqrt n [\bar X - \lambda ] \rightarrow n[0, \lambda] $$ so by the delta method  $$ \sqrt n [g(\bar X) - g(\lambda) ] \rightarrow n[0,(g'(\lambda))^2 \lambda] .$$ If we let $ g(\lambda) = \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n\lambda}$ then this implys that $$ \sqrt n \left[\left( \frac{n-1}{n} \right)^{n\bar x} - \left(\frac {n-1}{n} \right)^{n \lambda}\right] \rightarrow n\left[0, \lambda \left( \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n \lambda} \ln{\left(\frac{n-1}{n} \right)^n} \right)^2 \right]. $$ I get the right answer is I use $\lambda \left( \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n \lambda} \ln{\left(\frac{n-1}{n} \right)^n} \right)^2$ as the $\sigma^2_{UMVUE}$ but the condition was not met for the definiton of the ARE since the $\tau(\theta)$ my problem does not match like it requires in the definition of the ARE. However I noticed that $\left(\frac{n-1}{n} \right)^{n\lambda} \rightarrow e^{- \lambda}$ so I was wondering if that is good enough or is there another step that I need to take.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $g(x)$ in delta method could not depend on $n$. It shoud be the same function under various $n$.

Consider the logarithm of estimator: 
$$
\ln\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n \bar x}=n\bar x\ln\left(1-\frac1n\right).
$$
This is asymptotically normal estimator of $-\lambda$: 
$$
\sqrt{n}\left(n\bar x\ln\left(1-\frac1n\right)-(-\lambda)\right)=
\sqrt{n}\left(n\bar x\ln\bigl(1-\frac1n\bigr)+\bar x\right)-\sqrt{n}(\bar x -\lambda)=\underbrace{\bar x\sqrt{n}\left(n\bigl(-\frac1n+O\left(n^{-2}\right)\bigr)+1\right)}_{\stackrel{p}{\to}\,0}-\underbrace{\sqrt{n}(\bar x -\lambda)}_{\to N[0,\lambda]} \to N[0,\lambda]. 
$$
We use Slutsky's theorem in last step.

After that we can use delta method with $g(x)=e^x$, and find that
$$
\sqrt{n}\left[\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^{n \bar x}-e^{-\lambda} \right]\to N[0,\left(g'(-\lambda)\right)^2\lambda]. 
$$

Comment: Could you explain how you got this term $\bar x\sqrt{n}\left(n\bigl(-\frac1n+O\left(n^{-2}\right)\bigr)+1\right)$  ?

Comment: We can calculate the limit of $\sqrt{n}\left(n\ln\bigl(1-\frac1n\bigr)+ 1 \right)$ and see it goes to $0$ and then use Slutsky's Theorem, but im still interested on how you got the term I originally asked about.

Comment: @n.e. It is Taylor expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ at $x=0$, i.e., $\ln(1+x) = x-x^2/2+x^3/3+... = x + O(n^{-2})$.

Comment: @n.e. Yes, as V.V. said, this is Taylor expansion of logarithm at zero.

Comment: @NCh I was looking at this problem again and I agree  with your answer but using  the asymptotic variance that you came us with doesnt match with the answer in the solution manual. The asymptotic variance for the MLE is $ \lambda e^{-2 \lambda} $ and according to the work you have shown above, it is also the asymptotic variance for the UMVUE which means the ARE would be 1 but this isnt the answer in the solution manual. The answer in the solution manual for the ARE is  $ \left( \dfrac {e^{-\lambda}}{(\frac{n-1}{n})^{n \lambda}\ln (\frac{n-1}{n})^n}\right)^2 $.

Comment: @NCh I am able to get this answer by using the asymptotic var I came up with in my question but by using the $g$ function that didnt satisfy the delta method requirements.

Comment: This only means that the solution in the manual is completely wrong. This answer can appear only if $g(x)$ is like you took above, which is unacceptable.

Comment: @NCh I agree, thanks for the help